# stderr not correctly set is the cause of missing output in my program. Is there an appropriate way to find out this cause, aside from guessing?

Tags: python, node.js, debugging, subprocess, stderr

I already found out the reason of my failed Python code, but I found it by chance. Therefore, I am here to ask how you will debug the program if you were me. Below, I will tell about the bug in my program, provide the buggy codes, and how I debugged and found out the hidden problem of my codes.

The code is a Python code, which has a Node.JS subprocess inside. When the subprocess runs, Python prints everything it gives. If there is "correct choice" string, it prints "NICE.". The bug is that "NICE." is never printed.

A.js

```
num = 98
async function f(){
    // Check condition
    for(var i = 0; i < 10;i++){
        await sleep(4000);
        if (num < 100) {
            console.log("Enter number greater then 100");
            num++;
        }
        else {
            console.error("correct choice");
        }

    }
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
f();
```

B.py

```
import subprocess, sys
process = subprocess.Popen(['node', 'A.js'], bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):

    print(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if line.startswith("correct choice"):
        print("NICE.")
    else:
        continue  # skip it
```

HOW I FOUND THE ANSWER:
I tried to do threading, and then append everything read to a list. Then, I found out that "correct choice." is not in the list, but strangely printed. Then, totally by guessing, I found out the problem is because I am missing "stderr= subprocess.STDOUT" in subprocess.Popen().

Once again, how will you debug the code above, and fix the missing "NICE."? Just try to forget the solution and debugging processes I mentioned when you are answering this question.

Comment: You could use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` so that both outputs will be combined in `process.stdout.readline`

Comment: May I ask another question, why is it that without `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, I can still get the "correct choice" message printed, even it is not successfully read by `process.stdout.readline`? It sounds like a bug?

Comment: Since you haven't redirected stderr it retains its original connection to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, finally got the theory behind.